# Custom SharePoint Designer 2007 Workflow Activity Works on Test Server, but not production

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-actions, workflow-activity

Right now I have a Custom Workflow Activity, I've developed on a test server and it's working fine.  However when bundled into a .wsp on the test server and deployed to production, SharePoint Designer 2007 doesn't even see the workflow.  I've already checked the following:

- GAC on production server, it's there, same version as test

  Workflow .actions file is perfectly in sync between test and
      production

  Opened up the .cab and checked the feature.xml file,
      all looks ok.

I'm guessing it's a server sync issue of some sort, but where would I start from here?

EDIT: It's a farm scoped feature, verified it's installed and deployed.

Comment: I would also check the web.config settings, because sometimes, web.config doesn't contain the tags for register custom actions and also, another missing tags can result in problematic experience in SPD.

Answer (score 1):

I would check to verify the feature is enabled at whichever scope it is set (Farm, WebApplication, Site, or Web).

Comment: Good idea, though I checked and it's enabled.

Comment: Have you tried retracting, removing, reading, and redeploying it?

Comment: I would, but at this time we just made a business decision not to proceed further with the issue.  So ultimately we won't test.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the workflow activites are registered in web.config by your feature. For e.g.

```
 <System.Workflow.ComponentModel.WorkflowCompiler>
    <authorizedTypes>
      <authorizedType Assembly="System.Workflow.Activities, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Workflow.*" TypeName="*" Authorized="True" />
```